# Can you create a list of pairs? Not a list of list

Tags: list-manipulation, output-formatting

Is it possible to get this:{(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(x3,y3)......} -> This is a list of pairs. Not a list of list.

x would be the input into a function, y would be the output.

If not, I will have to create my own Pair function. Pair[Mod[x,6],{x,1,5}]]->

{(1,Mod[1,6]),(2,Mod[2,6])......} -> {(1,1),(2,2),(3,3).....}

Comment: In Mma the brackets like `(...)` are reserved to fix the order of operations only. The expression `(x,y)` has no sense in Mma. As much as I understand your intentions, you need the nested list (which you call "list of lists") like `{{x1,y1},{x2,y2},...}`. If you post operations and/or results that you are after we could show you how to operate with such a nested list.

Comment: `Table[pair[RandomInteger[20], RandomInteger[20]], 5]` gets you a list of 'pairs' like `{pair[13, 5], pair[8, 15], pair[4, 8], pair[10, 8], pair[1, 12]}` - why you'd want to use this instead of a list of lists is beyond me.

Comment: `{#, Mod[#, 6]} & /@ Range[5]`

Comment: You could get a list of those “pairs” as strings. But as others have said, this syntax does not make any sense in Mathematica. If you are looking to use the python interpreter, you’d want to make a list of lists, then turn the inner most list of each pair set to the format you want it to be in.